# NULL pointer for bmBits after converting a bit array to HBITMAP

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

I'm trying to convert a pixel array to a `HBITMAP` as instructed in this post:  [How to convert an Array of pixels to HBITMAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930528/how-to-convert-an-array-of-pixels-to-hbitmap).

Basically, the array is converted to a `HBITMAP`and then verified by copied to the clipboard. However, when accessing the bit value from the `BITMAP` construct by its `bmBits` member, it returns `NULL`.

I might have something missing here. If a `HBITMAP` is created successfully, why we still get a `NULL` pointer to its bit values?

```
uint8 width = 160;
uint8 height = 120;

uint8* pixels = new uint8[160 * 120 * 4];
for (int i = 0; i < 160 * 120 * 4; i++){
    pixels[i] = (i % 4 == 1) * 255; // testing pixels
}

BITMAPINFOHEADER bmih;
bmih.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
bmih.biWidth = width;
bmih.biHeight = -1 * height;
bmih.biPlanes = 1;
bmih.biBitCount = 32;
bmih.biCompression = BI_RGB;
bmih.biSizeImage = 0;
bmih.biXPelsPerMeter = 10;
bmih.biYPelsPerMeter = 10;
bmih.biClrUsed = 0;
bmih.biClrImportant = 0;

BITMAPINFO dbmi;
ZeroMemory(&dbmi, sizeof(dbmi));
dbmi.bmiHeader = bmih;
dbmi.bmiColors->rgbBlue = 0;
dbmi.bmiColors->rgbGreen = 0;
dbmi.bmiColors->rgbRed = 0;
dbmi.bmiColors->rgbReserved = 0;

HDC hdc = ::GetDC(NULL);

HBITMAP hbmp = CreateDIBitmap(hdc, &bmih, CBM_INIT, pixels, &dbmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
if (hbmp == NULL) {
    ::MessageBox(NULL, L"Could not load the desired image", L"Error", MB_OK);
    return NULL;
}

::ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);

// a little test if everything is OK
OpenClipboard(NULL);
EmptyClipboard();
SetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP, hbmp); // I can verify the image by pasting
CloseClipboard();

// verify the bitmap
BITMAP bitmap;
::GetObject(hbmp, sizeof(BITMAP), &bitmap);
uint8* lpbits = (uint8*)bitmap.bmBits;

assert(lpbits != NULL); // Why this assertion failed??

// cleanup
// DeleteObject(hbmp);
```

Comment: call GetLastError to see why the call failed - at least you will get a clue

Comment: @pm100: most GDI functions don't use `GetLastError()` for error reporting, and that is certainly the case for the GDI functions used in this example (only the clipboard functions do).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Fair enough. So no way to get anything other than 'well that didnt work'. However if some underlying thing failed (file error) then GetLastError will return something (although it could be a red herring)

Comment: Despite its name, `CreateDIBitmap()` actually creates a DDB instead of a DIB. The reference tells that it once had a flag `CBM_CREATDIB` which is no longer supported.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is in the [`GetObject()` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144904.aspx):

> If `hgdiobj` is a handle to a bitmap created by calling `CreateDIBSection`, and the specified buffer is large enough, the `GetObject` function returns a `DIBSECTION` structure. In addition, the `bmBits` member of the `BITMAP` structure contained within the `DIBSECTION` will contain a pointer to the bitmap's bit values.
>
> **If *hgdiobj* is a handle to a bitmap created by any other means, `GetObject` returns only the width, height, and color format information of the bitmap. You can obtain the bitmap's bit values by calling the `GetDIBits()` or `GetBitmapBits()` function.**

This means that `bmBits` is populated only when querying a DIB bitmap for a `DIBSECTION` structure, which contains a `BITMAP` amongst other things.

You are querying a DDB bitmap for a `BITMAP` structure, so `bmBits` does not get populated, and you have to retrieve the pixel bits separately.